# Understanding AngularJS ng-src

Tags: angularjs, directive

As explained [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc), the AngularJS directive ng-src is used to prevent the browser from loading the resource (e.g. image) before the handlebars get parsed. I'm currently using the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img ng-src="http://localhost:8081/media/{{ path }}" />
</div>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.path = 'images/23694c70-04d7-11e3-9ba8-73fb00de24c4.png';
    }, 1000);
};
```

The path is being retrieved from a webservice. Because of this delay, the browser tries to load `http://localhost:8081/media/`, which causes a 404. Once the path is retrieved, the browser issues the correct request and loads the image.

What is the preferred method to prevent loading any resources until all data is ready?

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzwBt/1/) for an example illustrating my situation.

Comment: I am not sure if `ng-cloak` would help you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put the whole path inside the $scope variable. That way `ng-src` will wait until you provide it with the fully resolved path to the image:

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img ng-src="{{ path }}" />
</div>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var path = 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/';
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.path = path + '2149314222/square.png';
    }, 1000);
};
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wktwL/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Too bad angular isn't capable of evaluating the bindings within the ng-src and waiting for them to complete before loading the image..

Comment: Hm. If  we need to pass whole path  then why not to use simple `src` attribute? Anyway it will not load anything before `{{ path }}` will be present on the page

Comment: I think the browser will still try to load the {{path}} string it finds in <img src="{{path}}">

Answer (score 3):

## Info by example

---

Let's take this `blogitem directive`.
The examples above already show you how to set a default value.

---

***HTML :***

```
<blogitem ng-repeat="item in items" 
          bg-src="{{ item.image }}" 
          caption="{{ item.title }}"/>
```

***JS :***

```
.directive( 'blogitem', function()
{
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'js/app/directives/blogitem.html',
        replace     : true,
        // pass these two names from attrs into the template scope
        scope       : {
            intro : '@',
            bgSrc : '@'
        }
    }
} )
```

***HTML template :***

```
<article>
    <img ng-src="{{ bgSrc }}"/>
    <p>{{ intro }}</p>
</article>
```

---

Hopefully it helps by your understanding of the `ng-src`.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue also. One thing I noticed is that if the value for ng-src is undefined then no img is fetched. Therefore, I created a utility method to concat two arguments and return a value if and only if both arguments are defined. See below.

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img ng-src="{{MyUtil.strConcat('http://localhost:8081/media/', path)}}" />
</div>
```

```js
myApp.factory('MyUtil', function() {
    return {
        strConcat: function(str1, str2) {
            return (angular.isDefined(str1) && angular.isDefined(str2)) ? 
                (str1 + str2) : undefined;
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout, MyUtil) {
    $scope.MyUtil = MyUtil;
...
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amirjsf/grayH/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ng-src` to an empty string if the data has not been populated yet:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img data-ng-src="{{ path && 'http://localhost:8081/media/'+path || '' }}" />
</div>
```

when `path` is uninitalized, the condition would short-circuit and go to the `or` part and set the `data-ng-src` to `''` (empty string), thus not hitting the server.

Comment: Can you set `ng-src` to a relative path like this: `<img ng-src="/images/picture1.png">`?

Comment: Yes you can use. But if the string is already known, you don't need to use `ng-src`. a plain `src` would suffice. Use ng-src if you're interpolating variables into the html.

Comment: Not trying to hijack this QA.  Would you mind looking at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350727/how-to-use-img-ng-src-in-angularjs-on-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

In the latest, you can evaluate it like this:

```
ng-src="{{ methodThatReturnsString() }}"
```

Answer (score -2):

I am sure 100% work

First you have to make your query like this

```
select (select '../Images/'|| T_LANG2_NAME ||'.png' T_LANG2_NAME from T04222_T where T_LOG_ID = T04220.T_C_STATUS) TIMER from T04220 
where T_PAT_NO = '89004331' group by T_C_STATUS 
having max(T_ARRIVAL_DATE) = (select max(T_ARRIVAL_DATE) from T04220 where T_PAT_NO = '89004331');) then you write Code for Controller like this ( if (scope.T_PAT_NO) {
                debugger;
                $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/T04205/GetTimerImage',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ PatientCode: scope.T_PAT_NO })
                    }).
                    success(function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        var newDataJSON = JSON.parse(data);

                        scope.TIMER = newDataJSON[0].TIMER;

                    });
```

then html code like this

```
<input id="imTimer" type="image" src="{{TIMER}}" style="width: 80px;height: 80px" />
```