# Slider animation with ngAnimate in a ngSrc directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I have some code like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235271/3018275

So I wanted to do an animation like this http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation

But I've seen that ng-animate doesn't work with ng-src so i thought to use something with ng-show and a watch event to set a boolean variable, but i can't do this.

Anyone can suggest me something?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to make a directive for the slider but you could do something like this. Its missing some code but this is the approach you should have.

In your html:

```
<div id="image-slider" ng-style="sliderStyle">
    <div class="image" ng-repeat="(key, source) in imagesServingUrl track by $index" ng-style="imgStyle">
        <img class="productImage" ng-src="{{source.serving_url}}" ng-class="{'hideImg':(current!=key), 'showImg':(current==key)}" />
        <span class="arrow-right" ng-click="next(current+1)"/>
        <span class="arrow-left" ng-click="prev(current-1)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

`
And in your css:

```
img.showImg {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0, 0.5, 1) all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0, 0.5, 1) all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0, 0.5, 1) all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0, 0.5, 1) all;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0, 0.5, 1) all;
}

img.hideImg {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 0.47) all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 0.47) all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 0.47) all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 0.47) all;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 0.47) all;
}
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.next = function(next) {
  $scope.current = next;
  $scope.percent -= 100;
  return $scope.imgStyle = {
    transform: 'translateX(' + $scope.percent + '%)',
    width: $scope.sliderWidth,
    height: $scope.sliderHeight
  };
};
```