# Display image in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng

Not sure why my image's aren't being loaded by angular, here's what I've got:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="family in product.families | orderBy:'category'">
    <h3>{{family.category}}</h3>
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <img ng-src="{{family.image}}"/>
    </div>
</li>
```

`family.category` works, but my `ng-src` does not seem to be. When I look in the HTML of the loaded page all I see is `<img ng-src>`

**JSON Sytnax**

```
"families": [
    {
      "category": "Tablets",
      "image": "images/tablet.png"
    }
]
```

You can take a look at the live version of this [here](http://www.metsales.com/metropolitansales/microsite/elo/elo.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding AngularJS ng-src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235169/understanding-angularjs-ng-src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure image url is correct, try complete image url in json.

In chrome dev tools-> network check which url it in invoking.

--

I have low reputation can't comment.

Comment: Actually... this is right, yeah I was pointing to my un-updated JSON file, so it wasn't fetching any url's. Thanks for helping me realize that