# ng-src not displaying image

Tags: html, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm currently having trouble to display my picture using ng-src.

```html
<img ng-src="http://localhost:3000/images/{{image.image}}" class="img-circle" alt="User" style="width: 130px; height: auto;">
```

The data is there when I console log this

```js
$scope.image = products.userinfo[products.index];
```

I didn't get any errors. Here is the sample output that I get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weF0n.png)

Comment: Can you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18235271/5244968 Also please make sure the image actually exists on that URL :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<img ng-src="{{'http://localhost:3000/images/' + image.image}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be just image,

```
<img ng-src="http://localhost:3000/images/{{image.image}}"
```

and then ,

```
$scope.image = products.userinfo[products.index].image;
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that before but didn't work. Infact it give an error. Here's my situation, every time I go into the page, the image displayed, but when I reload the page, the image disappear.

Comment: probably its not getting assigned when you refload.

Comment: Hi  @AzinuddinAleleCha  since you are storing your image in scope variable you are losing it on refresh. Try to use localstorage to store image instead!